# How to use Column value to "IN" Clause? SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

TABLE: `Othercharges`:

```
CODE     NAME      PRIMARYKEY      GROUPBY     JAN      <- columns
WDS      WOOD          1           'NULL'      1000     <- values
FDS      FOOD          2           'NULL'      2000
WATER    WATER         3           'NULL'      3000
TOT      TOTAL         4            1,2
```

I want to get the value of `GROUPBY` and put it in `IN` Clause. Because I want to get the SUM of `JAN` using `GROUPBY` which is based on their `PRIMARYKEY`

Here is my code:

```
UPDATE othercharges
SET JAN = (SELECT SUM(jan) 
           FROM Othercharges 
           WHERE primarykey IN (groupby) AND code = code)
WHERE Groupby <> 'NULL'
```

Using the code above gets me `NULL` result:

```
CODE     NAME      PRIMARYKEY      GROUPBY     JAN      <- columns
WDS      WOOD          1           'NULL'      1000     <- values
FDS      FOOD          2           'NULL'      2000
WATER    WATER         3           'NULL'      3000
TOT      TOTAL         4            1,2        NULL     <- my code result
```

The supposed output:

```
CODE     NAME      PRIMARYKEY      GROUPBY     JAN      <- columns
WDS      WOOD          1           'NULL'      1000     <- values
FDS      FOOD          2           'NULL'      2000
WATER    WATER         3           'NULL'      3000
TOT      TOTAL         4            1,2        3000     <- the should be result
```

Comment: You could try something along the lines of `groupby like '%' + primarykey + '%'`. Not sure this is a great idea though.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use `in` for this.  The value `'1,2'` is a string of length three, just like `'abc'`.  It is not two elements, of some sort.

You can do what you want using `like`:

```
UPDATE othercharges
    SET JAN = (SELECT SUM(oc2.jan)
               FROM Othercharges oc2
               WHERE ',' + oc2.groupby + ',' like '%' + cast(othercharges.primarykey as varchar(255)) + '%' and
                     oc2.acctcode = othercharges.acctcode
             )
    WHERE Groupby <> 'NULL';
```

Also, you need table aliases for the comparison on `acctcode` to work.  And, you are assuming that `'NULL'` is a string.  If it is the database value, then don't use double quotes and `<>` is inappropriate.

Comment: Gordon, I think that it's better to change condition to:                WHERE ',' + oc2.groupby + ',' like '%,' + cast(othercharges.primarykey as varchar(255)) + ',%'  -- i.e. add comas to prevent unnecessary values in a case like that ',10,' like '1'

Comment: @gordon linoff the code you gave me still gives me  'NULL' results. Any suggestion?

Comment: @ChadJimenezCalamba I think value in groupby column is 'NULL' not null.If so, you need to put escape character for Groupby <> 'NULL' to Groupby <>'''NULL'''

Answer (score 1):

Is Group By is String or VarChar so the Effectively the value equals "1,2" in reality the code will not work because 
it needs like

" IN (1,2) "

not like

" IN ('1,2') "

hope you understand

Comment: I understand what you mean but any alternatives that i can use?

Comment: create another table which could return the list of groups as numbers<br/>like  IN (Select group from grouptable where key=primarykey) . i hope you understand .